# How can i get process suspended state?

Tags: delphi, winapi, pascal, lazarus

I want to check the process is suspended or not in delphi.
So I used the function below, but the function always return true.
How can i check the process suspended??

```
function ProcessExist(exeFileName: string): Boolean;
var
  ContinueLoop: BOOL;
  FSnapshotHandle: THandle;
  FProcessEntry32: TProcessEntry32;
begin
  FSnapshotHandle := CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);
  FProcessEntry32.dwSize := SizeOf(FProcessEntry32);
  ContinueLoop := Process32First(FSnapshotHandle, FProcessEntry32);
  Result := False;
  while Integer(ContinueLoop) <> 0 do
  begin
    if ((UpperCase(ExtractFileName(FProcessEntry32.szExeFile)) =
      UpperCase(ExeFileName)) or (UpperCase(FProcessEntry32.szExeFile) =
      UpperCase(ExeFileName))) then
    begin
      Result := True;
    end;
    ContinueLoop := Process32Next(FSnapshotHandle, FProcessEntry32);
  end;
  CloseHandle(FSnapshotHandle);
end;
```

Comment: this function doesn't check suspended state but only checks for running instance of `exeFileName`.

Comment: One can suspend threads, not processes, so I'm assuming that your interpretation of a suspended process is a process, where all threads have been suspended. This isn't very helpful information, though, since any process can call `CreateRemoteThread`, thereby "unsuspending" a process.

Comment: @IInspectable, you can suspend process (see undocumented `NtSuspendProcess` function).

Comment: @Victoria: As far as I know, that, too, iterates over all threads and suspends them. There is no entry in the process object that stores the suspend/resume state. Given that, my previous comment is still valid: Being suspended is not a property inherent to a process. So if you ask the question, whether a process is suspended, you have to keep in mind, how that answer is derived, to understand the consequences of using that answer.

Answer (score 4):

That code doesn't attempt to check whether or not a process is suspended. Rather it checks whether or not there exists a process with the specified executable file name.

I'm going to assume that the form of process suspension you wish to detect is simply the suspension of all threads in that process. To the best of my knowledge there is not documented way to achieve this and we must resort to undocumented methods. One such is described [here](https://vtopan.wordpress.com/2009/04/15/how-to-find-out-if-a-threadprocess-is-suspended-get-thread-state/):

> The basic steps to get to a thread's status information is the
>   following (knowing of course both the process ID (hence forth PID) and
>   the thread ID (TID)):
>
> 1. call NtQuerySystemInformation with SystemInformation set to SystemProcessInformation (5)
> 2. iterate over the array of SYSTEM_PROCESS_INFORMATION structures to find your PID (ProcessId member) of interest
> 3. iterate over the array of SYSTEM_THREAD structures (detailed below) to find the desired TID (UniqueThread member) and check the State and
>      WaitReason members; both must be set to 5 if the thread is suspended,
>      any other values otherwise
>
> As it's probably obvious to most people keen on system-level
>   programming, a process is suspended when all it's threads are
>   suspended, so all of them must be checked for the suspended status.

The linked article includes the necessary code.

Comment: `WaitForSingleObject()` returning `WAIT_ABANDONED` is documented as applying only to mutex handles, not thread handles. And besides, it doesn't make sense for a suspended thread to return an abandoned state anyway. Waiting on a thread handle only tells you if the thread has terminated, not if it is suspended.

Comment: @Remy I got that info from the web, but it is bogus. Perhaps it did in some ancient version of Windows, but even then I doubt it. Sorry, and thanks.

Comment: from article - *but if the WaitReason is non-null, the State must be 5* - this is wrong. if `ThreadState != StateWait(5)`  the `WaitReason` have no sense . more concrete it hold last wait reason. it can be `Suspended` too. so correct check for `Suspended` (enum `KWAIT_REASON` declared in *wdm.h*) must be `TH->ThreadState == StateWait && TH->WaitReason == Suspended`